# How to change ListTile background color when tapped?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've searched high and low, but cannot find a way to change the background color on a ListTile, for example when it is tapped by the user.

Does anyone have a solution to what seems like a common use case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58092611/10511266 might help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the background color of a [ListTile](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html), you can simply wrap it in a [Container](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) and change its `color` attribute. Afterwards you can change the color, when `onTap` of the `ListTile` is triggered.

Demo:

[image: Demo Gif]

Demo Source:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CustomTile()
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CustomTileState createState() => CustomTileState();
}

class CustomTileState extends State<CustomTile> {
  Color color;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    color = Colors.transparent;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text('Title'),
        subtitle: Text('Subtitle'),
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            color = Colors.lightBlueAccent;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I see...the ListTile has to be wrapped in another Widget like a Container (or Card). I wonder why the Flutter devs didn't just integrate this functionality directly into the ListTile and enable it's bg color to be changed without the wrapping...seems like a common use case. Thanks @anmol.majhail and Niklas. I didn't post any code because it wouldn't have helped in this instance. My code was a hot mess.

Comment: @pskink Yes I looked at InkWell. I like that it offers onTap, onDoubleTap and onLongPress handlers. Apart from that is there any advantage to using one approach over another, e.g. wrapping ListTiles in InkWell and not Container?

Comment: @LordNull see [ListTile#build](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/list_tile.dart#L458)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what that is illustrating. Can you explain briefly pls?

Comment: @LordNull it simply says that `InkWell` is used internally by every `ListTile` item

Comment: If that's the case why is onDoubleTap callback not available in ListTile? (It seems to have onTap and onLongPress.)

Comment: @LordNull ask the guy who wrote `ListTile` why he did not add it (`onTapDown` is not handled as well

Comment: In most use cases `onTapDown` and `onDoubleTap` is not needed while using a `ListTile`. If we would add all listeners, provided by the `Inkwell`, we'd also had to add all of them to `RaisedButton` and literally every other button.

With this solution we can keep the constructors short and clear. If extended support for **gestures** is needed, we can always wrap Widgets in an [InkWell](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) or [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html).

Comment: Thanks really I didn't understand it before

Answer (score 3):

As You Haven't Describes your Use Case or shared any Code i have shared sample code that Change `Listile` Color `onTap()`

```
class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Screen1State createState() {
    return new Screen1State();
  }
}

class Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {
  bool _color;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _color = true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Card(
        color: _color ? Colors.deepOrangeAccent : Colors.purpleAccent,
        child: ListTile(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _color = !_color;
            });
          },
          title: Text(
            'Title',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          subtitle: Text(
            'Subtitle',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a quick way to do it, without much code and customization, you can wrap it with `RaisedButton` like this :

```
RaisedButton(
  color: ...
  child: ListTile(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    ...
  )
```

)

You can also use many properties like elevation, highlight color, focus color and much more.