# Flutter: Mark ListTile as selected in drawer

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to mark the `ListTile` of the current page as selected but 2 days ago I'm looking for a general way to do it.

I saw examples like [this](https://gist.github.com/kashifmin/12937f801b5f98466722748555a45bea) one where you hardcode the tile ID and use a case to know which is the current `Tile`. My question is, what if I have, to exaggerate, 100 `ListTile`s? How do I change the `selected` attribute programmatically to the selected `Tile`? Or a more real case: I have a `Drawer` that changes shape in each release, so keeping a code with the hardcoded IDs is not useful. I hope you understand the idea.

I've been trying different solutions for days but none seems general enough to me.

Answer (score 3):

Simple create **enum** class like below.

```
enum DrawerSelection { home, favorites, settings}
```

Create enum object and pass pre-defined value if you want, in my case i pass home as selected ListTile item. Like below code.

```
class _MyHomePage extends State<MyHomePage> {
DrawerSelection _drawerSelection = DrawerSelection.home;
```

Then in ListTile use selected property and change enum onTap() like below code.

```
 ListTile(
              selected: _drawerSelection == DrawerSelection.home,
              title: Text('Home'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.home),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                setState(() {
                    _drawerSelection = DrawerSelection.home;
                    _currentWidget = MainWidget();                    
                    _appBarTitle = Text("Home");
                });
              },
            ),
 ListTile(
            selected: _drawerSelection == DrawerSelection.favorites,
            title: Text('Favorites'),
            leading: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);                 
              setState(() {
                  _drawerSelection = DrawerSelection.favorites;                 
                  _currentWidget = FavoritesWidget();                  
                  _appBarTitle = Text("Favorites");
              });
            },
          ),
ListTile(
            selected: _drawerSelection == DrawerSelection.settings,
            title: Text('Settings'),
            leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              setState(() {
                  _drawerSelection = DrawerSelection.settings;                 
                  _currentWidget = SettingsWidget();
                  _appBarTitle = Text("Settings");
              });
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it is just simple you can create a new class that have your data and the bool selected

```
    class Post {
      final bool selected;
      var data;

      Post({
        this.selected,
        this.data
      });
    }
```

now when you use LIstView.builder in the itemBuilder if list[index].selected is true then set the color to blue if not then let it white or whatever in the on tap or onpressed whatever you are you using save the last clicked index in a global variable(called savedIndex)-initialize it with (-1)- and change selected to true at the this list index,then if savedIndex wasnt equal -1 change list[savedIndex].selected=false.

---

global variable

```
int selectedIndex =-1;
```

and itemBuilder.

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext _context, int i) {


        return GestureDetector(

                child:
                Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                    color:_list[index].selected? Colors.blue:colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: _buildRow(_list[index]),) ,
                onTap: () {
                   setState(){
                        if(savedIndex!=-1){
                         list[savedIndex].selected=false
                         }
                       _list[index].selected=true;
                       savedIndex=index;
                    }
                 }
              );

      }
```

Comment: Yes, I had thought of that solution, but I was thinking of something more at the production level. Where should this global variable be assigned? How to share `Drawer` between different screens? Should I use the `ScopedModel` class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659805/persisting-appbar-drawer-across-all-pages-flutter

Comment: the second answer is the best this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/51661926/11252816

Comment: thats for the static drawer part as for any other question it seems i dont get what you really want

Comment: I've been looking at different approaches, and apparently the order from best to least option is: RxDart, `scoped_model`, `InheritedWidget`, `StatefulWidget`. I'm going to try the first two and as soon as I have something functional I'll put it as an answer. Thanks anyway!